# How to align icons to the right in Bootstrap 4 dropdown items using CSS flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

How would you make below menu with Bootstrap 4 in such a way that the icon on the right always remains, while the text is automatically cut off (with `&hellip;`) when it overflows.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a href='#' class='a nav-link dropdown-toggle' aria-expanded='false' data-toggle='dropdown'>Dropdown</a>
    <ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>
        <li><a href="page1.html" class='dropdown-item' role='menuitem'>Long title</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.html" class='dropdown-item' role='menuitem'>Cut off with</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I've attempted displaying the icon using pseudo element `::after`, but that does not allow for using ellipsis on the text. I've tried using two DIVs, with `float-left` and `float-right` which fails when they overlap.

I'm looking for a solution avoiding hard coded widths. I think the right direction is using CSS3 flexbox:

```
<li>
    <a href="page1.html" class='dropdown-item' role='menuitem'>
        <span class='title'>Long title</span>
        <span class='icon'><i class='fa fa-lock'></i></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.dropdown-item {display:flex; flex-direction:row}
.title {display:flex; margin-right: auto}
.icon {display: flex}
```

Unfortunately that approach does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't **"have to"** set the width for the title in order for ellipsis to work. You do, however, need to set its width (or its parent's width) to something less than its content's width so that it overflows. To do this trick, you can set the max width of the dropdown menu to 0:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    max-width: 0;
}
```

And based on OP we can use `flexbox` to style the title and the icon:

```
.dropdown-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.dropdown-item .title {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown link
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
            <span class="title">Action</span>
        </a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
            <span class="title">Long title another action</span>
            <i class="fa fa-lock fa-fw"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
            <span class="title">Cut off with another action</span>
            <i class="fa fa-lock fa-fw"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
  </li>
```

#### CSS

```
.dropdown-menu {
    max-width: 0;
}

.dropdown-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.dropdown-item .title {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

#### Result

[image]

**fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/175868/

Comment: Thanks, works great. The only odd thing is the need for justify-content and align-items on .dropdown-item. It doesn't seem necessary to me, but when left out, the icons oddly jump higher vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

I made the icon `position:absolute`.

Also, in order for ellipsis to be visible, u need to add width for the title.
Without width, how will the browser know, that the text has oveflowed.

```css
.dropdown-item{
  position:relative;
}

.title{
    width: 130px;/*Adjust width to control ammount of text visible*/
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-right: 7px;
}
.icon{
  position:absolute;
  right:20px;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a href='#' class='a nav-link dropdown-toggle' aria-expanded='false' data-toggle='dropdown'>Dropdown</a>
  <ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>
<li>
    <a href="page1.html" class='dropdown-item' role='menuitem'>
        <div class='title'>Long title title title</div>
        <i class='icon fa fa-lock'></i>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="page1.html" class='dropdown-item' role='menuitem'>
        <div class='title'>Long title title title</div>
        <i class='icon fa fa-lock'></i>
    </a>
</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```